# excel vba - indirect copy via row/col address?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with survey data where each column contains one survey. I now wish to copy specific cells of the currently reviewed survey and paste them into a format which later will be appended to an email. The code below is calculating the current column number of the survey under review and then attempts to copy a specific cell in that column, however, no data is pasted into the format.

Following code:

```
Sub test
Dim dataSheet, dataStart, dataSurvey As Range
    dataSheet = "MED-FB-YTD"                                                    ' name of the sheet where data is stored
    Set dataSurvey = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HeartBeat_Alert").Range("K5")         ' survey number of specific record  eg. 5
    Set dataStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HeartBeat_Alert").Range("K4")          ' column number of first survey of specified time period    eg. 307
    dataCol = dataSurvey + dataStart - 1                                        ' actual data column is (dataStart + dataSurvey) - 1        eg. = 5+307-1 = column 311


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HeartBeat_Alert")
        .Select
        Sheets(dataSheet).Cells(25, dataCol) = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value      ' copy room no
        Sheets(dataSheet).Cells(16, dataCol) = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value      ' copy arrival date
        Sheets(dataSheet).Cells(17, dataCol) = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value      ' copy departure date
    end with

end sub
```

It seems to me like the way I am trying to copy the data over is not working / supported, hence would appreciate some help.

Thanks,
A2k

Comment: avoid the use of the _With_ statement. it adds unreadibility to the code in most instances. in your example, `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HeartBeat_Alert")` ... `.Select` ... `end with` are actually this command `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HeartBeat_Alert").Select`.  use that instead.  also do no use `Select` function, as mentioned by @Michał Turczyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: `dataSheet` should be `String`, not a `Range` object.

You can omit declaration of `dataSurvey` and `dataStart` and use this (won't affect anything, so you don't have to do that):

```
dataCol = Sheets("HeartBeat_Alert").Cells(5, 11).Value - Sheets("HeartBeat_Alert").Cells(4, 11).Value
```

Another thing. If you don't have to `Select` sheet ("HeartBeat_Alert"), then don't, use just `.Cells(3, 2).Value` instead of `ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value` (it also shouldn't affect the result, but it is more efficient).

After these changes, it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, adapted your suggestions and rewrote a whole bunch of other subs as well. Still learning every day here ;)

Comment: @Michał Turczyn,  actually `dataSheet` is variant, because that is the undeclared default. only `dataSurvey` is declared as Range